How to access PNET1 through PNET0 in GCP using a IPSEC tunnel?
Good day,
I have a local Mikrotik at my house connecting to a VM in GCP through an IPSEC tunnel. The IPSEC tunnel is up. I can reach the VPC network connected to PNET0 through the Tunnel. I am trying to reach the network connected to PNET1 on my VM. PNET1 has internet access, but I can't access it through the IPSEC tunnel.
How do I gain access to PNET1 through PNET0  using the IPSEC tunnel?
I appreciate any help you can provide.
